# Как подсчитать число?

Tags: python, python-3.x, float, decimal

Есть список чисел наподобие:

```
9.76e-05
```

Нужно получить в таком формате:

```
0.00009760
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
float('{:f}'.format(9.76e-05))
```

Но выходит:

```
9.8e-05
```

Как получить число наподобие вышеприведенного формата(8 цифр после запятой в формате float)?

Comment: А зачем ты строку обратно к float приводишь? `f'{9.76e-05:.8f}'`

Comment: @vp_arth , Мне нужно в формате float. Если не переводить будет '0.000098'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, в чем проблема и какова цель. Число 9.76e-05 и число 0.0000976 - это одно и то же число. Если нужно для вывода на экран, то использовать обычное форматирование без перевода во float.

```
print('{:.8f}'.format(9.76e-05))
```